# using card reader to input into webpage

Tags: credit-card, ipad, cardreader

I have a generic card reader which is attached to tablet(iPad or Android) through USB cable. After I navigate to my webpage, when I swipe a credit card, I want the card details to be filled into the textboxes..

How can I achieve this, without building native apps.

Answer (score 0):

If your card reader supports keyboard emulation, you can:

1. set focus on your card input field
2. post-back or do an ajax post when your field receives the card swipe
3. store the swipe data in a hidden form field
4. update the UI to show the user that the card was accepted (show ****1234 in input field, expire date etc.) and that he can continue to checkout